# Hibernation causes reboot

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption, hibernate

I'm running LXDE, when I try choosing "Hibernate" from the power menu I get a `GDBus.Error.org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Operation not permitted` error.

To see whether the "underlying machinery" works I tried invoking `sudo pm-hibernate` from the command line.

Essentially the machine shut down without warning. When I restarted it it went through an apparently ordinary boot sequence. I'm guessing that it actually did successfully write the memory image onto the swap partition (which, likely not coincidentally, resides within a LUKS LVM) but had no idea it needed to look for it at boot.

I heard it mentioned that some kernel parameters should be passed by GRUB at boot-time, and of course I expect it to require the password/key to unlock my LUKS volume, but can somebody provide a little more information or point me in the right direction?

Later I'll worry about the operation-not-permitted access-denied error...

Thanks.